# Why the last child of unordered list is not always animated as expected?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to make a simple filterable gallery with plain JavaScript. I made a pen in codepen, in which I'm doing some experiments with colored divs. It still has a lot of work in order to make a better javascript code, but there is a weird behavior which I cannot see why is happening.

The strange behavior has to do with the last child of the list, which isn't always animated as expected. To be more specific:

-If I just select the "yellow" button, all filtered yellow boxes will animate as expected.

-If I first select the "all" button and then I select the "yellow" button, the 10th box isn't animated.

I tried several different things and I noticed that the problem is with the last child of list. For example, I deleted the 6,7,8,9,10 and then the same problem appeared with the fifth box.

I've also tried to completely remove the CSS child selector but the weird behavior still existed.

Any ideas why this might be happening?

https://codepen.io/FoteiniK/pen/oJmbeJ?editors=1010

```js
const allButton = document.getElementById("all");
const listItems = document.getElementsByClassName("item");
const blueButton = document.getElementById("blue");
const yellowButton = document.getElementById("yellow");
const redButton = document.getElementById("red")
const list = document.getElementById("list");

blueButton.onclick = () => {

  for (let item of listItems) {
    /*reset animation*/
    item.style.animation = " ";
    item.offsetHeight;
    item.style.animation = null;
    item.classList.remove("appear-items", "dissappear");
    item.classList.contains("blue") === false &&
      item.classList.add("dissappear");
  }
  list.classList.add("reorder");
};
yellowButton.onclick = () => {

  for (let item of listItems) {
    item.style.animation = " ";
    item.offsetHeight;
    item.style.animation = null;
    item.classList.remove("dissappear", "appear-items");

    item.classList.contains("yellow") ===
      false && item.classList.add("dissappear");
  }
  list.classList.add("reorder");
};

redButton.onclick = () => {

  for (let item of listItems) {
    item.style.animation = " ";
    item.offsetHeight;
    item.style.animation = null;
    item.classList.remove("dissappear", "appear-items");

    item.classList.contains("red") ===
      false && item.classList.add("dissappear");
  }
  list.classList.add("reorder");
};

allButton.onclick = () => {
  list.classList.remove("reorder");

  for (let item of listItems) {
    item.style.animation = " ";
    item.offsetHeight;
    item.style.animation = null;
    item.classList.remove("dissappear");
    item.classList.add("appear-items");
  }
};
```

```css
$time:0.6s;
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #afafaf;
  margin: 20px;
}

.list {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  order: 10;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: #e12345;
  margin: 10px;
}

.red {
  background-color: red;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  & button {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover {
      opacity: 0.6;
    }
  }
}

.reorder {
  // .item{
  //   animation:appear 0.5s;
  // }
  .item:nth-child(1) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-child(2) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 1;
  }
  .item:nth-child(3) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 2;
  }
  .item:nth-child(4) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 5;
  }
  .item:nth-child(5) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 4;
  }
  .item:nth-child(6) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 2;
  }
  .item:nth-child(7) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 1;
  }
  .item:nth-child(8) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-child(9) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 0;
  }
  .item:nth-child(10) {
    animation: appear $time ease-in;
    order: 1;
  }
}

.appear-items {
  animation: appear 0.5s;
}

@keyframes appear {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: scale3d(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
  }
  20% {
    opacity: 0.2;
    transform: scale3d(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  }
  40% {
    opacity: 0.4;
    transform: scale3d(0.4, 0.4, 0.4);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transform: scale3d(0.6, 0.6, 0.6) translateY(0);
  }
  80% {
    opacity: 0.8;
    transform: scale3d(0.8, 0.8, 0.8);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale3d(1, 1, 1);
  }
}

.dissappear {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="all but" id="all">all</button>
    <button class="blue but" id="blue">blue</button>
    <button class="yellow but" id="yellow">yellow</button>
    <button class="red but" id="red">red</button>
  </div>
  <ul class="list" id="list">
    <li class="item blue">1</li>
    <li class="item red">2</li>
    <li class="item yellow">3</li>
    <li class="item red">4</li>
    <li class="item yellow">5</li>
    <li class="item red">6</li>
    <li class="item yellow">7</li>
    <li class="item blue">8</li>
    <li class="item red">9</li>
    <li class="item yellow">10</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Not sure why only the last item is affected, but adding the `reorder` class in a timeout (even with 0) seems to fix this. `setTimeout(()=>list.classList.add('reorder'), 0);`. This is often necessary when removing / adding multiple classes that have transition or animation effects that depend on each other. Also, you don't need the first three lines in the for loops.

Comment: I haven't found the exact problem yet, but it has something to do with: `list.classList.remove("reorder");` When you press the all button, the reorder class is removed from the list and you have your animations bound to the reorder class. Seems like a timings issue. PS: If you'd use a simple variable modelling your list items, the entire JS will fit on a few lines.

Comment: Thank you both! @hsan that did the trick! I used these three lines to reset the animation, otherwise, it behaves in a strange way.